# Robolectric does not execute Runnable

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-handler

Robolectric (3.1) should be able to execute runnable posted to the handler.

```
@Test
public void shouldExecuteRunnable() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final boolean[] result = {false};
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result[0] = true;
            signal.countDown();
        }
    };

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.post(runnable);

    Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
    Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler();

    signal.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Assert.assertTrue(result[0]);
}
```

Test fails on assertion. Am I missing something?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Test
public void shouldExecuteRunnable() throws Exception {
    final boolean[] result = {false};

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            result[0] = true;
        }
    };

    ShadowLooper.pauseMainLooper();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);

    ShadowLooper.runMainLooperOneTask();

    Assert.assertTrue(result[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,
This fixed it:

```
        ShadowLooper threadShadow = shadowOf(thread.getLooper());
        threadShadow.runOneTask();
```